# Commutator under unitary transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, unitarity

How can I prove that the commutators are invariant under unitary transformations?
I'm studying quantum mechanics, so (maybe) my professor is talking about the commutator of hermitian operators.

Answer (score 4):

Under a unitary $U$, for which $U^\dagger U = UU^\dagger = \mathbb I$, any arbitrary operator $A$ transforms as
$$
A \mapsto A' = U^\dagger AU.
$$
You're being asked to show that if $C=[A,B]$, then $C'=[A',B']$, or in other words, that
$$
U^\dagger[A,B]U = [U^\dagger AU, U^\dagger BU].
$$
The proof is simple but it's for you to work out.

Comment: I thought I'd to show that $U^\dagger[A,B]U= [A, B] $

Comment: That identity is false ─ and it's a good exercise to come up with counter-examples that break it and understand how and why they work; a good place to start is in two-level systems and pull $A$, $B$ and $U$ from the Pauli-matrix set. You're being asked to show that *the operation of taking a commutator* is invariant under the transformation, i.e. that it doesn't matter whether you transform before or after taking the commutator.

Answer (score -2):

$$U^\dagger [A,B] U U^\dagger = [U^\dagger A U U^\dagger , U^\dagger B U U^\dagger]$$

$$ U^\dagger [A,B] =[U^\dagger(U A U^\dagger), U^\dagger( U B U^\dagger)] $$

$$ [A,B] = [A', B'] $$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange. I've converted your post to MathJax so it renders properly, but you might want to check I haven't made any mistakes.